# Adding text before a line in a file

Tags: powershell

I am looking to add the phrase "Try our new mobile app" into a file before a specific line.

Here is one location I want to add the phrase. (HTML formatting will come later.)

```
<tr>
**Try our new mobile app**
<p style="font-size:12px;margin: 1em 0;"><i>Sincerely, <br/> Customer Service </i></p>
```

I am stuck on having the script add the phrase in the line before the text.Here is what I have so far:

```
#Variables

#UPDATE THESE FILE PATHS TO MATCH THE TEMPLATE LOCATIONS ON YOUR MACHINE.
$FILES_LOCATION_EMAIL = 'C:\Users\SSteve\Desktop\templates\email'

#UPDATE TO THE PHRASES YOU ARE LOOKING FOR IN THE TEMPLATE.
$PATTERN = @("Sincerely","Questions","Sent by PSEG Long Island","This email was auto generated")

#----------------------------------------DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE-------------------------------------


#Loop the recorded array positions and insert the new text
ForEach ($PATTERN in $PATTERNS)
{
    Get-ChildItem $FILES_LOCATION_EMAIL -filter body.html -recurse | Get-Content | Select-String -pattern $PATTERN

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing scripts no need to be clever and do it all in one line.  I recommend not using pipelines and just doing things in a straightforward way...

```
$FILES_LOCATION_EMAIL = 'C:\Users\SSteve\Desktop\templates\email'
$PATTERN = @("Sincerely","Questions","Sent by PSEG Long Island","This email was auto generated")


$files = Get-ChildItem $FILES_LOCATION_EMAIL -filter body.html -recurse
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $content = Get-Content $files
    $output = ''
    foreach ($line in $content) {
        if ($line | Select-String $PATTERN)  {
            $output += '**Try our new mobile app**'
        }
        $output += $line  
    }
    $output | Out-File -FilePath $file.fullname  -WhatIf
}
```

Might not be the cleverest or fastest way.  But I think it works...